# CSRF protection for backend only struts2 app

Tags: java, rest, struts2, csrf, csrf-protection

I have a web app written in Java using struts2 framework with only backend APIs using REST protocol. I'm not adding any Frontend code in it though it does use cookies to Authenticate and Authorise requests. I've created another project for frontend which uses these APIs and renders the UI.
My question is how do I implement CSRF protection in my backend only app? Since I don't want to implement Frontend within the Java code, I can't use struts' `<s:token>` in forms and hence I'm not able to use `TokenInterceptor` and `TokenSessionStoreInterceptor`.

Is there any way I can make my app CSRF proof?

Do point out if there is a possible duplicate of this query.

Comment: You need to generate a token at some point during, say, the login process, and store it on the client side. How often/if you regenerate that token is up to you.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion @DaveNewton. It requires client change which I wanted to avoid. This approach is in consideration but will take a call on it only if I don't have any other way.